# How to pass a vector of variable names to a function in a within a function in r

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I'm coming from Stata and need to do some work in R for a specific project. Unfortunately, I haven't had much success with functional programming when trying to reference a vector of names in a dataframe within a function.

I've coded a function that will (1) create a dummy in my dataset for if the value is missing and then (2) convert the NA to a zero, using dplyr and lazyeval (below). I've been unable to pass a vector of variable names to this function within a second function.

The working function which performs the data modification:

```
dumfrmna <- function(dset, varn) {
  expr <- enquo(varn)
  x <- dset %>% summarise(sum(is.na(!!expr)))

  if(x > 0) {
    varname <- paste0(quo_name(expr), "_mis", sep = "")
    dset <- mutate(dset, !!varname := is.na(!!expr),
                   !!expr = ifelse(is.na(!!expr), 0, !!expr))
  }

  return(dset)
}
```

The second function that fails to pass character names as to the working function:

```
misdum <- function(dset, vlist = character(), type = "exclude") {

  #Err messages
  if(!(is.vector(vlist) & is.character(vlist))) stop("vlist must be a character vector of variable names")
  if(!((type == "include") | (type == "exclude"))) stop("type must take either \"include\" or \"exclude\"")
  if(type == "exclude" & length(vlist) > 0 & all(vlist %in% names(dset))) stop("vlist contains variables not in dset")
  if(length(vlist) == 0 & type == "include") {
    stop("If type == include, vlist must be specified")
  }

  # Create list of included vars
  else if(length(vlist) == 0 & type == "exclude") {
    vname <- colnames(dset)
  }

  else if(length(vlist) > 0 & type == "include") {
    vname <- vlist
  } 

  else if(length(vlist) > 0 & type == "exclude") {
    vname <- names(dest) %>%
      setdiff(vlist)
  }

  #Create missing dummy 
  dset <- sapply(vname, function(x) dumfrmna(dset, x))
  return(dset)
}
```

Additionally this fails when I try to apply that vector of variable names to the function in R. I've attempted to use various tactics like noquote(), as.name(), parse(eval()) to modify the vector of column names in the sapply in the second function, but that just breaks on the conditional in the first function. Is there anyway to strip the quotes of that vector name?

How should this code be structured in R?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to provide a small reproducible example to test the functions.  Here, we are using the inbuilt dataset `mtcars`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

data(mtcars)
```

Create some NA's in some columns.

```
mtcars$wt[5:6] <- NA
mtcars$qsec[7:9] <- NA
```

Changes in the `dumfrna` - In the `!!expr =` statement it should be `:=` also the LHS would take a symbol or character.

```
dumfrmna <- function(dset, varn) {
  expr <- enquo(varn)
   exprC <- quo_name(expr)
  x <- dset %>% summarise(sum(is.na(!!expr)))

   x
  if(x > 0) {
    varname <- paste0(quo_name(expr), "_mis", sep = "")
    dset <- mutate(dset, !! (varname) := is.na(!!expr),
                   !! (exprC) := ifelse(is.na(!!expr), 0, !!expr))
  }

  return(dset)
}
```

In the second function, we evaluate the argument for `dumfrna` i.e. `!! x`.  Here, we are assuming that `vlist` takes a character `vector` as argument

```
misdum <- function(dset, vlist = character(), type = "exclude") {


  if(!(is.vector(vlist) & is.character(vlist))) stop("vlist must be a character vector of variable names")
  if(!((type == "include") | (type == "exclude"))) stop("type must take either \"include\" or \"exclude\"")
  if(type == "exclude" & length(vlist) > 0 & all(vlist %in% names(dset))) stop("vlist contains variables not in dset")
  if(length(vlist) == 0 & type == "include") {
    stop("If type == include, vlist must be specified")
  }

  # Create list of included vars
  else if(length(vlist) == 0 & type == "exclude") {
    vname <- colnames(dset)
  }

  else if(length(vlist) > 0 & type == "include") {
    vname <- vlist
  } 

  else if(length(vlist) > 0 & type == "exclude") {
    vname <- names(dest) %>%
      setdiff(vlist)
  }

  #Create missing dummy 
  dset <- map(rlang::syms(vname),  ~ dumfrmna(dset, !! .x))
  return(dset)
}
```

Try the functions with the data

```
res <- misdum(mtcars, vlist =c("wt", "qsec"), type = "include")
map(res, head, n = 9)
#[[1]]
#   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb wt_mis
#1 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4  FALSE
#2 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4  FALSE
#3 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1  FALSE
#4 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1  FALSE
#5 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 0.000 17.02  0  0    3    2   TRUE
#6 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 0.000 20.22  1  0    3    1   TRUE
#7 14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570    NA  0  0    3    4  FALSE
#8 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190    NA  1  0    4    2  FALSE
#9 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150    NA  1  0    4    2  FALSE

#[[2]]
#   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb qsec_mis
#1 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4    FALSE
#2 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4    FALSE
#3 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1    FALSE
#4 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1    FALSE
#5 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15    NA 17.02  0  0    3    2    FALSE
#6 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76    NA 20.22  1  0    3    1    FALSE
#7 14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570  0.00  0  0    3    4     TRUE
#8 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190  0.00  1  0    4    2     TRUE
#9 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150  0.00  1  0    4    2     TRUE
```

Comment: This is really helpful (also thanks for spotting the error in the first program). I'm still a little confused why the base function as.name() doesn't work, but the syms() function does. It seems non-intuitive that an object of class name wouldn't work in a function, when it does work in the console, but an object of class symbol would work in the function and not the console. Is there a good resource on how objects work in functional programming? Hadley Wickham's doesn't seem to go into great detail on this.

Comment: @Michael  There are vignettes written for rlang and dplyr/quosures.  Can you check on that

Answer (score 0):

This approach simplifies some of the dplyr expressions to use base R indexing.
Here the `dumfrmna` function accepts a dataframe with single column only,

```
library(dplyr)

# function takes a single data frame column, and
# returns the unchanged column if there are no NAs otherwise
# returns NA s changed to zero and an additional column named with 
# _mis as a suffix. 
dumfrmna <- function(df_column) {
  x <- sum(is.na(df_column))
  if(x > 0) {
    # new column, suffixed _mis,  with TRUE for NAs
    varname <- paste0(names(df_column)[1], "_mis")
    df_column[varname] <- is.na(df_column[[1]])

    # zero out the NAs in his single column
    df_column[is.na(df_column[[1]]),1] <- 0
  }    
  return(df_column)
}

misdum <- function(dset, vlist = character(), type = "exclude") {

  #Err messages
  if(!(is.vector(vlist) & is.character(vlist))) stop("vlist must be a character vector of variable names")
  if(!((type == "include") | (type == "exclude"))) stop("type must take either \"include\" or \"exclude\"")
  if(type == "exclude" & length(vlist) > 0 & 
     !all(vlist %in% names(dset))) stop("vlist contains variables not in dset") # mod !all
  if(length(vlist) == 0 & type == "include") {
    stop("If type == include, vlist must be specified")
  }

  # Create list of included vars
  else if(length(vlist) == 0 & type == "exclude") {
    vname <- colnames(dset)
  }

  else if(length(vlist) > 0 & type == "include") {
    vname <- vlist
  } 

  else if(length(vlist) > 0 & type == "exclude") {
    vname <- names(dset) %>%  ## mod dset
      setdiff(vlist)
  }

  # Create missing dummy by passing the single column -
  # the return from dumfrma is a dataframe with 1 or two columns 
  new_columns <- sapply(vname, function(x) dumfrmna(dset[x]), simplify = FALSE)
  dset <- bind_cols(new_columns)
  return(dset)
}

df = read.csv(text="
c1,c2,c3
a,1,11
b,2,12
c,NA,12
d,2,NA
", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# test the dummy insertion for a single column
dumfrmna(df["c1"]) ## should be unchangd
dumfrmna(df["c2"]) ## should add a column "c2_mis" and zero out the NA
dumfrmna(df["c3"]) ## should add a column "c3_mis" and zero out the NA

# test on the full frame
misdum(df, vlist = c("c2"), type = "exclude")

# > dumfrmna(df["c2"]) ## should add a column "c2_mis" and zero out the NA
# c2 c2_mis
# 1  1  FALSE
# 2  2  FALSE
# 3  0   TRUE
# 4  2  FALSE
# 
# > dumfrmna(df["c3"]) ## should add a column "c3_mis" and zero out the NA
# c3 c3_mis
# 1 11  FALSE
# 2 12  FALSE
# 3 12  FALSE
# 4  0   TRUE
# 
# > # test on the full frame
#   > misdum(df, vlist = c("c2"), type = "exclude")
# c1 c3 c3_mis
# 1  a 11  FALSE
# 2  b 12  FALSE
# 3  c 12  FALSE
# 4  d  0   TRUE
# >
```

Comment: Great! This also works. Is there any advantage to doing this in base R? Coming from Stata, the tidyverse syntax seems much more intuitive with regard to how data are modified.

Comment: @Michael, i use the tidyverse heavily and generally favor it. In this case the eval and quote stuff just seemed so complicated when the basic dynamic indexing capability of base R `[varname]` seemed simpler. Note also, though some simplicity comes from making the` dumfrmna` operate on a single column  -- perhaps the dplyr solution would simplify a bit as well with that thinking.